# Closed-form expression for combinatorial summation with a quadratic exponent?

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, st.statistics, binomial-coefficients

In a current project, I have encountered sums of the form $$A_N(\theta_1,\theta_2) = \sum_{x=0}^{N}{N \choose x} \theta_1^x \theta_2^{x^2}$$ for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ positive reals. My current use-case has $N\leq 10$, making numerical evaluation easy. However, I am hoping that there may be a simplified (non-summation) expression for $A_N(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. When $\theta_2=1$, the expression can be simplified by use of the binomial theorem, but the interesting cases have $\theta_2\neq 1$.